# BZWhll.WhllObj: Class not registred.. but it is? Transforming VBA-Makro to Win10 / 64bit

Tags: vba, ms-word, bluezone

This is my first question here, so be please gracious, while i'll offer a virtual debut-drink to everyone reading this.. cheers! :)

In my company the Migrationproject to Win10 is going on all over the landscape. We are using BlueZone Emulation from Rocket and Word-Makro scraping stuff from it. I have this VBA-Function, which works brilliant in the former environment:

```
Dim bz As Object
Function isInitilized() As Boolean
  isInitilized = False
  ...
  Set bz = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")  <--- ERROR  
  c.Connect "A"
  ...
  ...
```

Errormessage:

**Runtimeerror -2147221164 (80040154). Class not registered.**

All references are checked in the references-menu: BZExtr, BZPCom, BZRefl, BZWhll

So I tried with early-binding:

```
  Dim bz As BZPCOMLib.WhllObj
  Set bz = New BZPCOMLib.WhllObj <--- SAME ERROR
```

Here the IDE even offerend me the codecompletion which made me feel confident but.. BEEP!

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you are using 64-bit Office then that component you want to use must also be 64-bit.  This is why many people are still using 32-bit Office despite being on a 64-bit OS...

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to the hint from @Tim Williams solved by.. MYSELF! :)
The available BlueZone-Libary was the 32-bit version indeed. It is located in C:...program Files (x86)... You can see that in the VBA-Reference-Menu.

It is strange though that you can add the reference and the IDE behaves normal. No error until you try to use it in runtime.

We will discuss the installation of BZ 64-Bit or change to some other Data-Source/technology. Falling back to 32-bit office is no option.

thx Tim.